# How to get AccesToken from an Insights Hub (Mindsphere) Asset using node-red

Tags: rest, node-red, mindsphere

In node red there is a node (mindconnect) to send data to Assets on Insights Hub (Mindsphere), but I also want the read data from these assets. To do this I wanted to do a GET http request, but for this I need an Access Token.

Does anyone know of a way for me to get this access token in node red?

I found this:
https://documentation.mindsphere.io/MindSphere/howto/howto-selfhosted-api-access.html
and this:
https://documentation.mindsphere.io/MindSphere/howto/howto-agent-access-token.html

I don't understand how to use this and apply it to get the access token in node-red